# docker-compose build throwing error ERROR: Untar re-exec error: signal: killed: output:

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, quorrajs

I'm trying to setup docker for a existing QuorraJs application.
(https://quorrajs.org/docs/v1/preface/quickstart.html) however i'm having issues when trying to run docker-compose build.

I am still quite new to docker, not sure what i am doing wrong.

[image]

## docker file

```
FROM node:latest

MAINTAINER Erkan Demir <erkan.demir@peopleplan.com.au>

#Add everything in the current directory to our image
ADD . /var/www

RUN cd /var/www; \
   npm install \
   npm install -g quorra-cli \

EXPOSE 3000:3000

CMD["quorra ride"]
```

## docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'
services:
web:
    container_name: quorra-web
    build: .
    ports:
        - '3000:3000'
    volumes:
        - .:/var/www
    links:
        - db
    depends_on:
        - db
db:
    container_name: quorra-db
    image: mysql
    ports:
        - '3000:3000'
    volumes: 
        - /var/lib/mysql
    environment:
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
        MYSQL_DATABASE: Petbarn_DB
        MYSQL_USER: root
        MYSQL_PASSWORD: password
```

Comment: I think you try to use `FROM ubuntu:latest` for dockerfile

Comment: @ThanhNguyenVan it still throw the same error.

Comment: can you show more the error log ?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently there are some things wrong in your Dockerfile, try running it as follows:

```
FROM node:latest

MAINTAINER Erkan Demir <erkan.demir@peopleplan.com.au>

#Add everything in the current directory to our image
ADD . /var/www

RUN cd /var/www/ && \
   npm install && \
   npm install -g quorra-cli

EXPOSE 3000

CMD['quorra', 'ride']
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `&&` and remove last `\` in your Dockerfile:

```
...
RUN cd /var/www; \
   npm install \
   && npm install -g quorra-cli
...
```